# VB.net Update Label Each Second

Tags: vb.net

In my application i have a label that displays the current time in HH:mm:ss

How can i get the label to update its content each second so that the time actually is correct?

Comment: Have you tried using a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Timer` to your project. Set the Interval property to 1000. Then...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = 'Your code
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, just started wondering about how it could work using a timer by the time your comment arrived. By the way, will this need alot of RAM/CPU. Updating something each second could be quite a bit of work right?

Comment: It is not the Timer that could slow things down; it is the label repaint but try it and see. I don't think it should be too slow. If my answer was helpful, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: If you are afraid of the process slowing down the cpu then you can use a background worker.

Comment: The Timer is low priority so it wont go off at exactly 1 sec(1000 ms) - which can make a countdown control seem  to "skip" a second every now and then,  If you use 750 to 850, you can usually avoid that

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow i know, i just set my timer to 500ms so the skips are too small to be noticed by the user